# How to use xpath count in Fitnesse (Xebium)

Tags: xpath, fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

The headline basically says it all.

In Chrome and Firefox I can use the following expression:

```
count(//tbody/tr[contains(@id, 'myTable:0')])
```

It returns the number 2.

When I try to use this in Fitnesse (Xebium) it says that the execution of the command failed.

Is there a way to count the number of rows in my table in Fitnesse (Xebium), through xpath-expression.

Comment: would it be because ot `tbody` added by Chrome or Firefox parser (happens all the time)? try without, `count(//tr[contains(@id, 'myTable:0')])`

Comment: paul t: It seems like Xebium doesn't understand it is an xpath expression if it doesn't start with a slash ( / )